# Calculate ship speed given latitude and longitude in a loop

Tags: matlab, loops

I would like to read certain lat and lon values and calculate ship speed in a for loop every minute.  One minute represents every 480th row.  I'm not really sure how to do this in a loop.

```
Lat = table2array(timepositionrawdata1150seq(:,2));
Lon = table2array(timepositionrawdata1150seq(:,3));

for i=1:480:42072  

lat1100 = Lat(1);
lon1100 = Lon(1);
lat1101 = Lat(481);
lon1101 = Lon(481);
dist_1101 = 1000*(deg2km(distance(lat1100, lon1100, lat1101, lon1101)));
speed_1101 = dist_1101./60;
az_1101 = azimuth(lat1100,lon1100,lat1101,lon1101);
heading_1101 = az_1101 + 180;

end
```

Comment: `for i=1:480:end`? `end` of what? I think you need [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html).

Comment: My data finishes in the 42072nd row.  That is the end.  I'm unsure how to read every 480th row of lats and lons and reference it consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

You mean just this below?

```
Lat = table2array(timepositionrawdata1150seq(:,2));
Lon = table2array(timepositionrawdata1150seq(:,3));

for i=1:480:(42072-480)

  lat1100 = Lat(i);
  lon1100 = Lon(i);
  lat1101 = Lat(i+480);
  lon1101 = Lon(i+480);
  dist_1101 = 1000*(deg2km(distance(lat1100, lon1100, lat1101, lon1101)));
  speed_1101 = dist_1101./60;
  az_1101 = azimuth(lat1100,lon1100,lat1101,lon1101);
  heading_1101 = az_1101 + 180;

end
```